# What's wrong with this number format?

Tags: php, number-formatting

I want to echo the values from a MySQL column, but I want to get the commas in the thousand's places. So, instead of receive "5,000" I receive 5000. I am using number_format but it seems to be something wrong because the browser console shows "0,00" instead of the value I am calling via Jquery/Ajax. Some ideas? I inserted the numbers as strings. Example: ("INSERT INTO Votes (votes) VALUES ('10000')";
Maybe it has something to do?

This is my php code to fetch the data from MySQL:

```
$co = $_REQUEST['color'];

$sql = "SELECT SUM(votes) AS sum FROM Votes WHERE color = '$co'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo number_format($row["sum"], 2, ",", ".");
}
else {
echo "No result found";
}
```

Comment: If you just echo `$row["sum"]`, what do you get?

Comment: Running `echo number_format("5000", 2, ",", ".");` does print the expected result, so I suspect there is something wrong with `$row["sum"]`

Comment: Anis R. with just $row["sum"] I get the values, but without the commas, I want the thousand's commas.

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: And note that when an answer has proved helpful in some way, it's nice to upvote it rather than treat the contributor as some kind of lackey

Comment: Strawberry, that is not my intention, I am just getting used to this website, I am new and I am still trying to learn some things about web programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do `number_format("5000")` and you'll get `5,000` as result.

Extrapolated to your example, it will be:

`number_format($row['sum'])`

So for example, if $row['sum'] is 5000, you'll get 5,000 as output.

Comment: I am passing a variable with Ajax, so I can't put 5000. I am trying to retrieve a value from a MySQL table. Do you understand?

Comment: I thought you can extrapolate it, i suppose you're a beginer, sorry. Just edited the answer.

Comment: JoelBonetR, I tried number_format($row['sum']), but it gets 0,00 in the browser console.

Comment: You're working with PHP in the example so if you get 0.00 in browser's console you may have some error on another side. I tested it with different numbers before posting, and php function works as expected. Maybe you have some JavaScript manipulating the data that can provide?

Comment: Also check https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_func_string_number_format

Comment: JoeslBonetR, I added the number values as strings in the MySQL table, do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: I don't really think that can cause any issue here

Comment: Well... It can if there are any non-numeric character. Which values do you have on your db? Any whitespace, comma or similar?

Comment: Ok, this worked great. But I had to delete the Number() method from the Ajax call to use this. And I want that Number() method to return 0 if the value is an <empty string>.

Comment: Suppose that's another issue, this time in JavaScript side. If the issue described here is done, please mark as solved and write a new one with your js issue and your js code

Answer (score 1):

Well, in PHP what you are already doing is the right way to do it, I am not sure why you are getting a wrong output.

But alternatively, you can try to format the number directly from MySQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT FORMAT(SUM(votes), 2) AS sum FROM Votes WHERE color = '$co'";
```

By doing this, `$row["sum"]` should directly come formatted.

If even this does not work, then you most probably have a problem on the client-side.

Comment: Ok, when I do that, I receive NaN in the browser console. Again, I inserted the numbers in the MySQL table as strings. Do you think that's the problem?

Comment: Ok, this worked fine. But how can I show just the commas without the decimals dots?

Comment: @JoeSmith simply replace the 2 in `FORMAT(SUM(votes), 2)` by 0 (this is the number of decimal points you want).

Answer (score 0):

use number_format($row["sum"],2,'.','');